# stripe.dll conflict with other components

Tags: visual-studio-2015, stripe-payments

I started to work a project that is almost ready. now I need to add stripe component to work with it in Visual studio 2015. when I want to add the component from NuGet (the version is 21.7.0) it display an error:

> An assembly with the same identity 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

Comment: check the references for your project.  it seems as if the project builder believes that you already have a reference to `System.Net.Http.dll`.

Comment: There is a reference for the System.Net.Http, but I am trying to add Stripe.net as a reference and after that the error appear. I couldn't find any relation between this two

Comment: it could be a possibility that `Stripe.net` uses `System.Net.Http.dll`.  try removing your existing `System.Net.Http.dll` reference and try do add the `Stripe.net` component again